CUDA error: device-side assert triggered Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions. NLP - Transformers Roberta
I met this error in loss function. An example below:
My code was working normally, but something got lost, I can’t find the problem. I tried to update the libraries, test previous versions, checked tensors, indices… Can someone please help me, at the end of the page contains the link to my repository with the files I used.
Libraries version:
Windows 11
GTX 1050 TI (Driver-Version==552.12)
Python==3.12.3
transformers==4.39.3
tokenizers==0.15.2
torch==2.2.2+cu121
datasets==2.18.0
Cudatoolkit==12.1
CuDNN==8801

transformers-cli env:
- `transformers` version: 4.39.3
- Platform: Windows-11-10.0.22631-SP0
- Python version: 3.12.3
- Huggingface_hub version: 0.22.2
- Safetensors version: 0.4.3
- Accelerate version: 0.29.2
- Accelerate config:    not found
- PyTorch version (GPU?): 2.2.2+cu121 (True)
- Tensorflow version (GPU?): not installed (NA)
- Flax version (CPU?/GPU?/TPU?): not installed (NA)
- Jax version: not installed
- JaxLib version: not installed
- Using GPU in script?: <fill in>
- Using distributed or parallel set-up in script?: <fill in>

Vocabulary size:
5008

Input ID size:
Minimum ID: 0, Maximum ID: 5007

Example output input_ids:
input_ids: [[0, 304, 860, 1026, 261, 326, 1578, 16, 4891, 16, 507, 4109, 16, 300, 463, 285, 783, 1887, 432, 960, 16, 285, 2016, 315, 3550, 374, 325, 1819, 16, 924, 4846, 971, 1782, 18, 374, 1183, 3494, 16, 833, 575, 1083, 324, 285, 300, 463, 916, 1908, 2802, 358, 1209, 285, 262, 1026, 18, 276, 718, 354, 1952, 306, 276, 773, 358, 3488, 18, 367, 276, 1092, 285, 1020, 288, 1369, 464, 2414, 276, 2158, 271, 422, 312, 2926, 91, 87, 79, 93, 414, 276, 1891, 1647, 16, 285, 868, 4067, 271, 2379, 16, 271, 853, 288, 464, 753, 262, 1755, 263, 285, 288, 478, 956, 422, 3227, 265, 358, 4498, 271, 1005, 454, 16, 358, 646, 285, 262, 4539, 271, 264, 2955, 3879, 80, 18, 590, 463, 1503, 16, 285, 1186, 641, 271, 4372, 367, 989, 1111, 742, 1576, 637, 3559, 352, 334, 959, 16, 1417, 89, 594, 709, 600, 334, 439, 385, 3991, 315, 395, 70, 287, 402, 263, 1191, 1519, 1680, 16, 367, 334, 1042, 322, 575, 2165, 16, 957, 364, 1026, 16, 981, 874, 4127, 339, 4426, 594, 1766, 315, 285, 2286, 377, 18, 1168, 504, 17, 1534, 315, 1120, 3915, 285, 1077, 364, 4163, 4522, 366, 16, 315, 3915, 358, 1178, 263, 358, 2665, 931, 18, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 2921, 818, 712, 764, 276, 737, 325, 1782, 31, 1521, 295, 764, 4648, 285, 338, 339, 641, 798, 322, 2156, 262, 4559, 2445, 16, 285, 2145, 285, 322, 491, 2109, 579, 325, 662, 389, 271, 4013, 3642, 579, 4195, 624, 350, 280, 414, 276, 921, 315, 1939, 16, 325, 330, 333, 2907, 16, 285, 1507, 285, 322, 306, 1994, 289, 352, 300, 1392, 16, 607, 950, 352, 1543, 287, 2484, 1294, 16, 2405, 16, 4847, 18, 3008, 291, 4648, 16, 334, 1922, 263, 334, 1483, 491, 3094, 3210, 338, 339, 2325, 3291, 69, 31, 367, 1302, 16, 640, 359, 586, 3492, 304, 339, 935, 2997, 358, 4680, 285, 367, 334, 285, 2239, 304, 432, 2325, 325, 556, 18, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],

Code:
import os
import traceback
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = "1"
os.environ['TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA'] = '1'
import torch
from tokenizers.implementations import ByteLevelBPETokenizer
from tokenizers.processors import BertProcessing
from transformers import RobertaConfig
from transformers import RobertaForMaskedLM
from transformers import RobertaTokenizerFast
from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
from transformers import Trainer, TrainingArguments
from transformers import pipeline
from datasets import load_dataset

def read_document(document_path):
    with open(document_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        return file.read()

def main():
    try:
        # Create the directory if it does not exist
        if not os.path.exists('raw_model'):
            os.makedirs('raw_model')

        training_data = 'C:\\Users\\caiqu\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\IA\\crepusculoDosIdolos.txt'

        os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'raw_model')

        # Initialize a ByteLevelBPETokenizer
        tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer()
        tokenizer.train(files=[training_data], vocab_size=52_000, min_frequency=2, special_tokens=[
            "<s>",
            "<pad>",
            "</s>",
            "<unk>",
            "<mask>",
        ])

        tokenizer.save_model('raw_model')

        tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('raw_model', max_len=512)

        print("Vocabulary size: ", tokenizer.vocab_size)

        tokenizer._tokenizer.post_process = BertProcessing(
            ("</s>", tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids("</s>")),
            ("<s>", tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids("<s>")),
        )

        # Creating our Transformer
        config = RobertaConfig(
            vocab_size=52_000,
            max_position_embeddings=512,
            num_attention_heads=12,
            num_hidden_layers=6,
            type_vocab_size=1,
        )

        model = RobertaForMaskedLM(config=config)
        model.num_parameters()

        # Check if a GPU is available and, if not, use the CPU
        device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

        # Move the model to the device
        model = model.to(device)
        print("Model is using : ", next(model.parameters()).device)
        
        # Loading the dataset
        dataset = load_dataset('text', data_files=training_data)

        # Tokenizing the dataset
        def tokenize_function(examples):
            encodings = tokenizer(examples["text"], truncation=True, padding='max_length', max_length=512)
        
            # Opening the file in write mode
            with open('indices.txt', 'w') as f:
                # Writing the indices to the file
                f.write("input_ids: " + str(encodings['input_ids']) + "\n")
            
            return {"input_ids": encodings['input_ids']}

        tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True, num_proc=8, remove_columns=["text"])

        with open('results.txt', 'w') as f:
            for batch in tokenized_datasets['train']:
                input_ids = torch.tensor(batch['input_ids']).to(device)  # Add .to(device) here
                print("Inputs are using :", input_ids.device)  # Now should print 'cuda' if a GPU is available
                min_id = input_ids.min().item()
                max_id = input_ids.max().item()
                f.write(f'Minimum ID: {min_id}, Maximum ID: {max_id}\n')

        data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
            tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=True, mlm_probability=0.1
        )

        output_dir = os.path.abspath('C:\\Users\\caiqu\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\IA\\raw_model')

        training_args = TrainingArguments(
            output_dir=output_dir,
            overwrite_output_dir=True,
            num_train_epochs=1200,
            per_device_train_batch_size=64,
            save_steps=10_000,
            save_total_limit=2,
            prediction_loss_only=True,
        )

        trainer = Trainer(
            model=model,
            args=training_args,
            data_collator=data_collator,
            train_dataset=tokenized_datasets['train'],
        )

        # Check if the output directory exists before starting the training
        if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
            os.makedirs(output_dir)

        # Enable mixed precision
        trainer.train()

        trainer.save_model('raw_model')

        # Create a fill-mask pipeline with the model and the tokenizer
        fill_mask = pipeline(
            "fill-mask",
            model='raw_model',
            tokenizer='raw_model'
        )

        while True:  # Infinite loop
            question = input("You: ")  # Ask a question to the user
            if question.lower() == "exit":  # If the question is "exit"
                break  # Exit the loop
            response = fill_mask(question)  # Generate a response to the question
            print("AI: ", response)  # Print the response

    except Exception as e:
        with open('error_log.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(e))
            f.write(traceback.format_exc())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Error:
C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\accelerate\accelerator.py:436: FutureWarning: Passing the following arguments to `Accelerator` is deprecated and will be removed in version 1.0 of Accelerate: dict_keys(['dispatch_batches', 'split_batches', 'even_batches', 'use_seedable_sampler']). Please pass an `accelerate.DataLoaderConfiguration` instead:
dataloader_config = DataLoaderConfiguration(dispatch_batches=None, split_batches=False, even_batches=True, use_seedable_sampler=True)

C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\native\cuda\Indexing.cu:1290: block: [42,0,0], thread: [124,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\native\cuda\Indexing.cu:1290: block: [42,0,0], thread: [125,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\native\cuda\Indexing.cu:1290: block: [42,0,0], thread: [126,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
C:\actions-runner\_work\pytorch\pytorch\builder\windows\pytorch\aten\src\ATen\native\cuda\Indexing.cu:1290: block: [42,0,0], thread: [127,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\caiqu\OneDrive\Documentos\IA\treinar3.py", line 141, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\caiqu\OneDrive\Documentos\IA\treinar3.py", line 122, in main
    trainer.train()
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 1780, in train
    return inner_training_loop(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 2118, in _inner_training_loop
    tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 3036, in training_step
    loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 3059, in compute_loss
    outputs = model(**inputs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\models\roberta\modeling_roberta.py", line 1084, in forward
    outputs = self.roberta(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\models\roberta\modeling_roberta.py", line 828, in forward
    embedding_output = self.embeddings(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\transformers\models\roberta\modeling_roberta.py", line 130, in forward
    position_embeddings = self.position_embeddings(position_ids)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\sparse.py", line 163, in forward
    return F.embedding(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\caiqu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2237, in embedding
    return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.

Github Repositories: https://github.com/DonatoReis/bert-new
